# Drupal 7, Ubercart, Product search by price range

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart

I'm using Ubercart 3.x, Drupal7. Can anybody tell me how can I create a form for searching in products with price in specified interval? I.e. user should fill this form with minimum price in the interval and maximum price and after posting form he will see all suiting products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to create a view to do exactly this. if you haven't already done so, install the views module. create a new view, filer by type of product, and add two exposed filers on the price field, one greater than and one less than.

When you publish your view, the user will see a form with two fields, and can search for products in the specified price range.

Hope this helps. If you haven't used views before, it's worth perusing the documentation first.

James

Comment: Thank u for help. I've already tried to use exposed filters, but the problem is, how to place these filters at the right sidebar.

Comment: I've found it!) At the left side there is an option to move filter to the block))